# How can I restrict access/view images of other user uploaded using CK Editor

Tags: asp.net, image, ckeditor

I am using [CK Editor](http://ckeditor.com/demo), in my application every user have his separate email templates. I want to store images to user specific and user should not view other user uploaded images when browse to Server to upload images

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is point different user to to different image folder

for example: `root/<%=UserId%>/Image`